# Warning a user of an unsigned executable

Tags: clickonce, uac

I have a ClickOnce application that plays the role of a stub - it's a small application that simply downloads another installer. The way it works is that it downloads the payload, runs it and closes. It's written in C# .NET. My problem is the payload is dynamic. I want my ClickOnce application to display a warning to the user if the payload that the application downloaded is not signed. This behavior is automatically present when UAC is enabled, however my stub is run on many different OS's and I don't know if UAC is enabled or not. I would love it if I could simply invoke the warning that Windows does when an executable is run - is this possible? If not, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about the warning shown when running a program downloaded from a website.

You need to add a `Zone.Identifier` Alternate Data Stream to the file.
You can do that using [this library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ntfsstreams.aspx):

```
var fs = new NTFS.FileStreams(filename)
fs.Add("Zone.Identifier")
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(fs["Zone.Identifier"].Open()) {
    writer.WriteLine("[ZoneTransfer]")
    writer.WriteLine("ZoneID=4")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Win32, the function used to verify Authenticode signatures is `WinVerifyTrust`. There is no .NET BCL equivalent (as far as I know), but pinvoke.net has a pretty good article on how to use it from C#:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wintrust.winverifytrust